# onerror <img> tag attribute always fires in IE, why?

Tags: javascript, image, internet-explorer, onerror

I have code something like this

```
<a class="img" href="LINK">
  <img src="GOOD_IMG" title="title" onerror="src='ERROR_IMG'">
</a>
```

in FireFox and chrome it behaves as you would expect (shows GOOD_IMG if it exists and shows ERROR_IMG if not) but in IE (9) it always shows the ERROR_IMG.

If I debug in IE and on the fly set the `onerror` so something else e.g.

```
onerror="alert('error')"
```

then the alert message appears and the correct image is shown.

What could be causing IE to cause `onerror` to activate where the other browsers don't have a problem?

Is there someway I can find out what is causing the `onerror`?

Thanks

Comment: Try setting `onerror` to something like `myFunc(e)` and log `e` in the console

Comment: Works for me in IE8 and IE9: http://jsfiddle.net/LyZmq/ Could it be that IE doesn't recognize that specific image?

Comment: I've found that if it doesn't somehow immediately get the image, it will fire the `onerror`. We use this to our advantage in our application that dynamically sets the source of profile pictures from a database, so `onerror` fires and we set it to the default contact picture until the actual picture loads in.

Comment: MMM's method is what I would like to try but I don't know how to do this, can someone provide more information on this? (if I just do as said then I get "e is undefined")

Comment: Having this exact same issue

Comment: I can't get mine to fire. I'm setting `src` to an SVG, which IE8 doesn't support, but it still finds a resource at the URI provided so it won't throw the `onerror` invocation.

Answer (score 3):

I also experienced similar symptoms.
In my case, 'onerror' occurred by putting 'empty' value in `src` at `<img>`.

**Problem:**

html

```
<img src="" onerror="this.src='ERROR_IMG'">
```

js

```
$('._profile_image:first').attr('src', IMAGE_URL);
```

**Solution:**

```
<img onerror="this.src='ERROR_IMG'">
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try like this. First you have to write one JS function for checking whether the image is exists or not (AJAX call return exists or not) and change the image accordingly.

Second you call the function on onerror event

```
function imgError(imageControl, path) {        
            $.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                async: true,
                url: "test.aspx/CheckImageExists",
                data: "{'imagePath':" + JSON.stringify(path) + "}",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function (response) {
                    if (response.d == "exists") {
                        imageControl.src = path;
                    }
                    else {
                        imageControl.src = 'img/errorimg.jpg';
                    }
                }
            });
            return true;
        }

<img src="<%# "admin/"+ Eval("imagath") %>" onerror="imgError(this,'<%# "admin/"+ Eval("imagath") %>')">

C#
 [WebMethod]       
        public static string CheckImageExists(string imagePath)
        {
            string fullPath = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath.ToString() + imagePath;
            fullPath=fullPath.Replace('/','\\');
            return File.Exists(fullPath) ? "exists" : "notexists";           
        }
```